# html2canvas error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Error parsing CSS component value, unexpected EOF

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas for a project.  The code was downloaded from https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js

This is my use case:

```js
setInterval(function(){
    html2canvas(document.documentElement).then(function(canvas){
        log('<a href="'+canvas.toDataURL("image/png")+'">View a screenshot of the current page</a>',false);
    });
},10000);
```

When I open up the log file (the `log` function appends messages to a log file) then everything looks good - I can click on the link and view the screenshot.  When I open up the console, however, I see this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Error parsing CSS component value, unexpected EOF
```

This wasn't there before I added html2canvas, and I simply took html2canvas and started using it.  Although the output isn't corrupted/incorrect, I think that it would be cleaner if the error was resolved.

Since it isn't my code making the error (I think), I'm not sure on how to approach this problem.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Recommend turning on the `debug` option to get more verbose logging from html2canvas, and you should always include `.catch()` in order to deal with the unhandledpromise rejection. if the debug logs don't clue you in, post them here. Also are you using any non-same-origin images in your CSS properties?

Comment: Also check this page to ensure your CSS is compliant: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features

Comment: @RandyCasburn: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration I didn't add any configuration and the logging is default set to true, and it does log everything.

Comment: So what about my other questions then? Are you 100% certain you've created 100% compliant CSS? Do you have any images that are cross-origin? Why don't you have a `.catch()`??

Comment: @RandyCasburn: Well... the CSS is not under my control.  This is supposed to take a screenshot of whatever page you're on for later.  I think that applies to images that are crosss-origin too, but not sure.  I'll add a catch to it right now, just wait a moment.

Comment: The CSS may not be under your control, but using a tool creates an obligation to determine if it will work, even on the uncontrolled source. Open the browser dev tools and look at the CSS on the page to determine if it is compliant with the limitations of html2canvas. You can determine this.

Comment: @RandyCasburn: I added a `.catch( function(e){ console.log(e); } );` and on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405496 I am getting `Unsupported Image type` in the console.  So I will try to determine if the CSS is valid, because that seems to be an important thing here.